# Distribute labeling function over a list in order to assign different labels in a PieChart

Tags: list-manipulation, labeling, charts

I have a PieChart:

```
PieChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

I want to label each sublist differently, but

```
  PieChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, ChartLabels -> {{"l1", "l2", "l3"}, {"l4", "l5", "l6"}}]
```

does not work, because the first part of the Labellist will be associated with the row label. So I thought the only solution to this will be to assign a Label to each entry separately by using `Labeled`

But then I got stuck with distributing the `Labeled` function over the values list. For example, given the list of values for the PieChart:

```
labList = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

I can apply `Labeled` to each element in this list:

```
labeledStuff = Map[Labeled[#, "Label"] &, labList, {2}]
```

But how to apply a different label to each element? That is, given the list with labels:

```
labels = {{"l1", "l2", "l3"}, {"l4", "l5", "l6"}}
```

apply each of these labels to each element of the value list, resulting in the following:

```
{{Labeled[1,"l1"],Labeled[2,"l2"],Labeled[3,"l3"]},{Labeled[4,"l4"],Labeled[5,"l5"],Labeled[6,"l6"]}}
```

Comment: Try `PieChart[MapThread[Labeled, {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{"l1", "l2", "l3"}, {"l4", "l5", "l6"}}}, 2]]`.

Comment: Aha `MapThread` is the function I need, god I love mathematica, thanks a bunch ;)!

Comment: @J.M: Quick follow-up question: What if I want to supply options to `Labeled` like `Background->Red` or `LabelStyle->Red` or something? I tried `PieChart[MapThread[
 Labeled[#1, #2, 
   LabelStyle -> Red] &, {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{"l1", "l2", 
    "l3"}, {"l4", "l5", "l6"}}}, 2]]` but get an error message

Comment: `LabelStyle` won't work in that case, yes. Try `PieChart[MapThread[
  Labeled[#1, Style[#2, Red]] &, {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{"l1", "l2", "l3"}, {"l4", "l5", "l6"}}}, 2]]`.

Comment: I see, thank you again!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
labels = {{"l1", "l2", "l3"}, {"l4", "l5", "l6"}};

PieChart[Thread[Labeled @@ #] & /@ Transpose[{data, labels}]] (* or *)
PieChart[Thread /@ Thread[Labeled[data, labels]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Always multiple solutions with mathematica ;)...like that one as well, thanks!

Comment: @holistic, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.